# Hadoop mobile application

Tags: android, hadoop

We are students and planning to port Hadoop on android platform. Can anyone suggest a hadoop application that would justify use of a MapReduce framework on mobile application?

Comment: Hi Paresh, Hadoop is an open source Apache project. It is programmed in java. you can have its source code at "http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/"                   Hadoop is a MapReduce framework and offers distributed platform for large scale data processing. It is widely used for data analysis.            "developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/" is a good tutorial for beginners. It also has Hadoop installation steps.                                                          "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, Second Edition" is a good reference book to go into details of Hadoop.

Comment: The source code is @ http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/, the mirrors mentioned above are for the binary jar files.

Answer (score 6):

I can think of two usefull applications

1. Some kind of management console on android that allows me to control a cluster.
2. Perhaps there is a need for mobile applications that defer the required compute power to a remote cluster.

Running a cluster on android itself seems like a waste of effort to me because of the processing power and battery limitations.

Comment: Thanx Niels for ur feedback. This is a research project and We are optimistic about ongoing progress in processing power of mobile OS. But I agree with you about battery limitations. For now we are interested because of the convenience that this architecture would provide to create mobile based internal private cloud for an organization. It would be so convenient if you need to migrate your whole physical architecture from one site to another. you just need to take all Hadoop configured mobiles (datanodes) and a namenode from one place to other and start your wifi.

Comment: @Selva I have absolutely no clue what you are asking.

Comment: would it be a waste of time if the device was plugged into AC power? I think you could have a check to see if the device is plugged in and it could contribute to processing over night.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Niels Basjes.. I am working on a project now in my final year of engg in Pune.. I myself wanted to do something like this.. My project involves running mapreduce jobs on the log files generated from a website and deriving useful statistics from it and displaying it as a graph.. Amongst the things I thought about was to use an android phone and call mapreduce jobs from it. The jar file of the job will reside in the server. Once the server makes computations, it can give back the result to the android phone in form of a graph.. SO in my opinion, having hadoop on android phone wont serve any purpose as having a cluster of 200 MB phone memory is as good as not using hadoop at all.. You could instead try something else where the computing power of hadoop is realized by making client(android phone)/server(hadoop server) calls..

Answer (score 2):

I think porting Hadoop on Android makes a lot of sense if one looks a bit into the future. Mobile devices are getting more and more powerful with octa core devices just around the corner. Also modern phones or tablets have lots of GBs of RAM. 
ARM powered devices consume less power than comparable Intel based devices. One example would be to use Apache Nutch on a farm of ARM powered devices that also use Hadoop.

Answer (score 2):

I am final year computer science student and newbie to hadoop. But I would like to tell few things.
True spirit of distributed system is ability to sum up all small processing units to perform tasks that are not feasible with single device. So, It is really worthwhile to implement hadoop on small and portable devices that have small but significant processing power and more in quantity. Portability also adds another benefits here.

Here are some applications that could be implemented in distributed environment. Although I am not sure whether they can be implemented using hadoop or not!

1. Distributed multiplayer game. We can develop intensive multiplayer games for mobile devices.
2. Distributed video transcoding.
3. Distributed web server for small organizations.